# Combining Trimmean and averageif whilst avoiding #div/0

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have some data which I would like to average. I have used averageif to partition sections based on other cell values (1). I have then added a criterion (2) using averageifs to ignore #DIV/0!. Now I would like to add a trimmean function (3) and now it doesn't work and I have no idea why! (I get the horrid #DIV/0!)

(1)  `=AVERAGEIF(C4:C3349,"Step 1b",E4:E3349)`

(2)  `=AVERAGEIFS(E4:E3349,C4:C3349,"1b",E4:E3349,"<>#DIV/0!")`

(3)  `=AVERAGEIFS(E4:E3349,C4:C3349,"1b",E4:E3349,"<>#DIV/0!",E4:E3349,"    <"&PERCENTILE(E4:E3349,.9),E4:E3349,">"&PERCENTILE(E4:E3349,.1))`

Any ideas?

I can't change the data or fix the datalogger and would rather not have to delete the #div/0!s one by one!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how `PERCENTILE` works but the error is due to the `#DIV/0!` in your `E4:E3349`. If you wrap your column with an `IFERROR` the output is not `#DIV/0!`. Something like this,

```
=PERCENTILE(IFERROR(E2:E6,0),0.9)
```

This additional zeroes may or may not affect the result. I am not sure.